# turing a 3d matrix so 3rd dimension becomes the 2nd dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix

My problem stems from concatenation. I have a 3D matrix defined as Z (rows) x X (columns) x Y. I can vertcat onto the Z dimension fine. I can horzcat can onto the X dimension fine. But not the Y axis, because horzcat only adds onto the 2nd dimension (according to the help file).

To stress, I am not trying to expand the original matrix.

- the original 3D matrix (MGeol) has a values for the geological region cells sit in.
- I work out where the regions change by subtracting slightly smaller versions of the MGeol matrix, offset by one, in the Z, X and Y directions. The result is that non zero values are at the contact between regions.
- To get those all of those results back into a same size matrix as the original so I can line them up with the coordinate vectors.

So I add layer of zeros onto the offset dimension and concatenate. Its work for rows(Z) and columns(X) but how do I manipulate Z to horzcat and keep order?

```
Zcontact = MGeol(1:nz-1,:,:) - MGeol(2:nz,:,:);

Zcontacts = vertcat(Zcontact, zeros(1,nx,ny)) - vertcat(zeros(1,nx,ny), Zcontact);

Xcontact = MGeol(:,1:nx-1,:) - MGeol(:,2:nx,:);

Xcontacts = horzcat(Xcontact, zeros(nz,1,ny)) - horzcat(zeros(nz,1,ny), Xcontact);

Ycontact = MGeol(:,:,1:ny-1) - MGeol(:,:,2:ny);

Ycontacts = horzcat(Ycontact, zeros(nz,nx,1)) - horzcat(zeros(nz,nx,1), Ycontact); %<- causes the error

Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Comment: Have you tried `cat`, rather than `horzcat`? It is the more general function, of the form `cat(DIM,A,B)`. So, try `cat(3,Ycontact,zeros(nz,nx,1),)`? See my more thorough answer.

Comment: You might look at the functions `permute` (and `ipermute`) and `shiftdim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I'd change my comment to an answer, seeing as I suspect it will work this way:

`vertcat` works by concatenating along the 1st dimension (rows). `horzcat` works by working along the 2nd dimension (columns). The more general form of the function is `cat(DIM,A,B)`, which concatenates `A` and `B` along the dimension, `DIM`.

So, for your case, try:

```
Ycontacts = cat(3,Ycontact, zeros(nz,nx,1)) - cat(3,zeros(nz,nx,1), Ycontact);
```

Comment: Not a problem, @user1502755. If you feel that it has answered your question, feel free to press the 'tick' button, to accept my answer. :)